# z-index ordering not correctly rendering in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

Currently, I am working on making an accordion table which fades and expands to show a selected row displaying content it contains.  For the most part, I have been able to get things working without any issues.  I am having a problem with how the content displays in IE.

This first image is the desired effect and it is how it is currently rendering in Firefox and Chrome.
[image: Firefox]

This image is not the desired effect and how it is currently rendering in Chrome (and IE).
[image: Internet Explorer]

I have tried several things involving adjusting z-index but none have worked.  My current testing code can be found here:[Codepen](http://codepen.io/goblinlord/pen/obqrdE?editors=0100).

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) {
    if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) {
      throw new TypeError('Cannot call a class as a function');
    }
  }

  function setMargins($table) {
    var w = $table.innerWidth();
    $table.find('.pad').each(function(i, ele) {
      $(ele).css({
        width: (w - ($table.data('tableW') | 0)) / 2
      });
    });
    $table.find('.details .content').each(function(i, ele) {
      var $ele = $(ele);
      var innerW = $ele.innerWidth();
      $ele.css({
        left: (w - innerW) / 2
      });
    });
  }
  var collapseTable = function() {
    function collapseTable($table, tableW) {
      _classCallCheck(this, collapseTable);
      if (!$table instanceof jQuery)
        $table = $($table);
      this.$table = $table;
      if (tableW | 0)
        $table.data('tableW', tableW);
      var scope = this;
      this.$table.on('click', '.collapser', function() {
        scope.collapse();
      });
      this.$table.on('click', '.row', function() {
        scope.collapse();
        var $this = $(this);
        var $details = $this.prev();
        var h = $($details.children('td')[0]).innerHeight();
        if (!$details.find('.content'))
          return;
        $details.addClass('open');
        $this.addClass('open');
        $this.css({
          height: h,
          padding: 0
        });
      });
      this.$table.find('.row').each(function(i, ele) {
        var $ele = $(ele);
        $ele.data('h', $ele.innerHeight());
        $ele.height($ele.innerHeight());
      });
      $(window).on('resize', function() {
        setMargins(this.$table);
      }.bind(this));
      setMargins(this.$table);
      this.$table.show();
    }
    collapseTable.prototype.collapse = function collapse() {
      this.$table.find('.open').each(function(i, ele) {
        var $this = $(ele);
        $this.removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
        $this.height($this.data('h'));
      });
    };
    return collapseTable;
  }();
  window.collapseTable = collapseTable;
}());

var t = new collapseTable($('.collapseTable'), 500);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.collapseTable {
  display: none;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
}
.collapseTable table {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  empty-cells: show;
}
.collapseTable .details {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
.collapseTable .row {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: .99;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
.collapseTable .row.open {
  opacity: 0;
  color: transparent;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.collapseTable .details .content {
  position: relative;
  left: 30px;
  margin: 1em 0;
  width: 300px;
  background: blue;
  opacity: .99;
  padding: 4em;
}
.collapseTable .details {
  align-content: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
.collapseTable .details.open {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapseTable">
  <table>
    <tr class="details">
      <td>
        <div class="content collapser">
          <pre>
          f asdfs ;lkfdsja  fas
          
          f sa
          sfda 
          sdaf 
          dsaf
          sdaf 
          sd fa 
          ds
           fa
           d
          </pre>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row closed">
      <td class="pad"></td>
      <td>
        asf
      </td>
      <td>
        asf2
      </td>
      <td>
        asf2
      </td>
      <td>
        asf2
      </td>
      <td class="pad"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="details">
      <td>
        <div class="content">
          <pre>
          sf sd ksd sda
           fsd
            fds
             sd
             af d
             as 
             dfa 
             sdf 
             sa
              fds
              
          </pre>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row closed">
      <td class="pad"></td>
      <td>
        hgf
      </td>
      <td>
        hgf
      </td>
      <td>
        asf2
      </td>
      <td>
        asf2
      </td>
      <td class="pad"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="details">
      <td>
        <div class="content">
          <pre>
          sf sd ksd sda
           fsd
            fds
             sd
             af d
             as 
             dfa 
             sdf 
             sa
              fds
              
          </pre>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row closed">
      <td class="pad"></td>
      <td>
        hgf
      </td>
      <td>
        hgf
      </td>
      <td>
        asf2
      </td>
      <td>
        asf2
      </td>
      <td class="pad"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="details">
      <td>
        <div class="content">
          <pre>
          sf sd ksd sda
           fsd
            fds
             sd
             af d
             as 
             dfa 
             sdf 
             sa
              fds
              
          </pre>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row closed">
      <td class="pad"></td>
      <td>
        hgf
      </td>
      <td>
        hgf
      </td>
      <td>
        asf2
      </td>
      <td>
        asf2
      </td>
      <td class="pad"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

***Edit:***
I successfully corrected the issue in Chrome but it is still rendering incorrectly in IE.

Comment: i've noticed a while back that `z-index: -1` only hides in firefox... set an opaque blocker in front at z-index=1 and change the -1 to 0.

Comment: Any thoughts as to how to accomplish the same effect in a way which would work across browsers?

Comment: @dandavis Thanks, I will give that a shot.

Comment: @dandavis Actually, wouldn't the blocker then still block my other rows? =/... that wouldn't exactly accomplish what I am going for unfortunately.

Comment: not if you make the other ones 2 or 3 or 100 or whatever. in short, move everything up 2, then add your blocker.

Comment: ah yeah makes sense.  Working on adding it now ^^.

Comment: actually, i couldn't get that to work either since children can't be set lower than their parent... or maybe i misunderstand...

Comment: @dandavis Setting z-index: 0 on .details.open blocks click events to the rows that need to receive them.

Comment: hah... I got it... gah... this is some silly stuff.  Will post details in a few as the answer with reference in a few as the answer was rather obscure.

Comment: or not =/... still off in IE.  I was able to get it working in Chrome though by setting opacity for ".collapseTable .details .content" and for ".collapseTable .row" both to .99.  Also, setting visibility to hidden for .row.open to allow click events through.  Reference: http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Answer (score 0):

if you add "background-color:grey" in class ".collapseTable .open.details" then I hope it should work accross browser.

Comment: Not sure how this is supposed to help anything.  The background of the table is already grey.  The problem is during animation the content is displaying above the lower table rows which is not desired.  Setting the background to grey completely hides the lower table rows until the animation is complete (overlaying on top them is not desired).

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention that you will have to add z-index:5 in ".collapseTable .details .content{" class.

please try it now.

Comment: Doing this doesn't seem to fix anything.  It just ends up hiding the lower rows behind the content.  The desired effect is having the content hidden behind the lower rows as the div is expanded to the height of the content.